# How to create custom db model function in Django like `Greatest`

Tags: django

I have a scenario that, i want a greatest value with the field name. I can get greatest value using `Greatest` db function which django provides. but i am not able to get its field name. for example:

```
emps = Employee.objects.annotate(my_max_value=Greatest('date_time_field_1', 'date_time_field_1'))
for e in emps:
   print(e.my_max_value)
```

here i will get the value using `e.my_max_value` but i am unable to find out the field name of that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to annotate a [Conditional Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) using `Case()` and `When()`.

```py
from django.db.models import F, Case, When

emps = Employee.objects.annotate(
    greatest_field=Case(
        When(datetime_field_1__gt=F("datetime_field_2"), 
            then="datetime_field_1"),
        When(datetime_field_2__gt=F("datetime_field_1"), 
             then="datetime_field_2"),
        default="equal",
     )
)
for e in emps:
   print(e.greatest_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the database query to tell you which of the fields was larger, you'll need to add another annotated column, using case/when logic to return one field name or the other. (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when)

Unless you're really trying to offload work onto the database, it'll be much simpler to do the comparison work in Python.